# Wiremock not recording

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to use wiremock to record request/responses for a `REST api`.

When I run in record mode, **no mappings are generated**. Only the 2 folders 'mappings' and '__files' are created.

I am running the api on localhost and hitting it at http port.

This is the command I am using:

```
java -jar wiremock-1.57-standalone.jar --port=9999 --proxy-all="http://localhost:9090" --record-mappings
```

I also tried giving the entire endpoint including resource path. I am sending a POST request.

Have someone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I'd upgrade to the latest version, 2.6.0 (As of April 2017) -
 https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/releases

Please verify:

- That the endpoint you are sending your `--proxy-all` to is working if you hit it directly.
- That this command (which will proxy all traffic to `google.com` instead) records traffic: `java -jar wiremock-1.57-standalone.jar --port=9999 --proxy-all="https://www.google.com" --record-mappings`